# Can this "real set" disconnect complex n-space?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Hi everyone: Suppose $E\subset \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is a closed set with empty interior, and $ D $ a domain in $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ with $n\geq2$.  Can we conclude that the open set $ D\setminus E $ is connected?

Comment: E is a real set? What is this difference?

Comment: do you mean that we should view $D$ as a subset of $\mathbb R ^{2n}$?

Comment: Well, even $\mathbb C^n\setminus \mathbb R^n$ is connected when $n\ge 2$ ...

Comment: The set $E$ is inside $\lbrace z=x+i0: x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$. We can consider $D$ as part of $ \mathbb{R}^{n} $.

Comment: Henning Makholm: I think you are right, but  how would you prove it?