# Connectedness of $\mathbb{C}^{n}\setminus \mathbb{R}^{n}$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Hi everyone: How would you prove this classic result: if $ n\geq2 ,$  then $\mathbb{C}^{n}\setminus \mathbb{R}^{n}$ is connected? Any reference? Thanks.

Comment: Hey, apparently [I'm a classic](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2091048/can-this-real-set-disconnect-complex-n-space#comment4297918_2091048)!

Comment: @HenningMakholm: Well, of course :)

Comment: Generally $\mathbb R^k\setminus V$ is easily seen to be path-connected if $V$ is a linear subspace of dimension at most $k-2$. Now set $k=2n$.

Comment: @M.Rahmat, please don't ask the same question twice, it's not well received here.

Comment: Hint: Prove first for $m>k$ that a vector space of dimension $m$ over $\mathbb{R}$ minus a subspace of dimension $k$ over $\mathbb{R}$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{R}^{m-k} - 0$.

Comment: You can prove that it's path connected.

Comment: @AlexM. I think it's safe to say that this is a more specific question; a logical followup to Henning's comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proof sketch:

- Prove there is a path between any two points with all nonreal coordinates
- Prove there is a path from any point to a point with all nonreal coordinates

Comment: Counterexample: Let $$\omega^{+}_{j}=\lbrace z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}^{n}:z x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n},y_{j}>0\rbrace$$
and 
$$\omega^{-}_{j}=\lbrace z=x+iy\in\mathbb{C}^{n}:z=x+iy, x,y\in\mathbb{R}^{n},y_{j}<0\rbrace$$
for $j=1,2,...,n$. Then  set
$\Omega_{1}:=\bigcup_{j=1,2,...,n}\omega^{+}_{j}$ and 
$\Omega_{2}:=\bigcup_{j=1,2,...,n}\omega^{-}_{j}.$
The disjoint open sets $\Omega_{1}$ and $\Omega_{2}$ form a partition of $ \mathbb{C}^{n}\setminus\mathbb{R}^{n} $ and so it is not connected.

Comment: @M.Rahmat $\Omega_1 \cap \Omega_2 \neq \varnothing$. If $j\neq k$, then $\omega_j^+ \cap \omega_k^- \neq\varnothing$.

Comment: @M.Rahmat: Also, in both bullet points, I only put constraints on the endpoints, not on the path itself. The reason for the splitting is to allow one of the, IMO, obvious ways to construct paths: work one coordinate at a time. In the case of the first bullet point, this construction automatically avoids points with all real coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

The set that you are interested in is path connected.  Consider $(z_1,\cdots,z_n),(w_1,\cdots,w_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n\setminus\mathbb{R}^n$.  Since $(z_1,\cdots,z_n)\in\mathbb{C}^n\setminus\mathbb{R}^n$ there is at least one index $i$ where $z_i$ is not real (some of the other indices can be real, points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ have *all* coordinates real).  Similarly, there is some index $j$ where $w_j$ is not real.  We construct two paths.  There are two cases:

Case 1: $i\not=j$.

Step 1: While keeping $z_i$ fixed, transform all $z_1,\cdots,z_{i-1},z_{i+1},\cdots,z_n$ into $w_1,\cdots,w_{i-1},w_{i+1},\cdots,w_n$.  This can be done with a linear homotopy $(1-t)z_k+tw_k$ changes $z_k$ into $w_k$ as $t$ varies between $0$ and $1$.  This never intersects $\mathbb{R}^n$ since the $i$-th coordinate is never real.

Step 2: While keeping all other coordinates fixed, transform $z_i$ into $w_i$.  Since the $j$-th coordinate is not real, this path never intersects $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Case 2: $i=j$.  In this case, let $k$ be an index other than $i$.  Consider the path that keeps all other coordinates fixed and transforms $z_k$ into the complex number $0+1i$ ($i$ is not an index here).  Then use Case 1 on $k$ and $j$.

Comment: Can some explain why the question I asked is "off topic" please?

Comment: Can someone explain why this question "closed as off topic" please?